# How to fetch resources in database for Internationalization

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I did the localization is using the resources in seperate .resx files.But my requirement is to work localisation with the sql database.I am little confused about to access the resuources from the database for the culture info
my code for .resx file is

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

any idea?

Comment: and why they want to access resource in database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617856/using-sql-for-localization-instead-of-resx-files-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

[Extending the ASP.NET 2.0 Resource-Provider Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx)